# Hand off variable to html

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

So instead paying $35 for slideshowpro for lightroom, I just decided to whip up a quick javascript slideshow to do a simple task. Rotate 10 images within a div, randomly.
It works like so:

```
var imageSrc = "source_folder/";
var imageType = ".jpg";
var randomImage = imageSrc + 0 + Math.floor(#*Math.random()) + imageType;
```

(This isn't all the code, I've left out the rest)

How do I take `randomImage` and insert into an `<img>` tag.

```
src="randomImage" will not work.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var imageSrc = "source_folder/";
var imageType = ".jpg";
var randomImage = imageSrc + 0 + Math.floor(#*Math.random()) + imageType;
document.getElementById('booba').src=randomImage;

....
....
....

<img id='booba' />
```

And if you want to be noty (not a good practice, but should work)

```
<img src='javascript:this.src=randomImage' />
```

Comment: Wouldn't work for me, I just get a box with an image-not-loaded box.

Comment: please alert the `randomImage` before `document.getElementById('booba').src=randomImage;`
And this will show you why. 
Or simply right click on the image->properties

Comment: Still nothing, the alert looks fine. I had to remove the + 0 from the randomImage, but it would alert out to something like source_folder/1.jpg (which does exist in the directory) but the <img> tag (which is located correctly) will not display anything in the div.

Comment: You have something wrong in either the path you use, ot the image name. If the src of the image gets a value, then this is done. Now you have to find out what is wrong with this value. I would copy the alerted string and past it manualy into the src attribute of an image in the same file/page, and see if it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the string "randomImage", use the variable:

```
image.src = randomImage
```

This is just setting the src to the path of the current image. There will be a delay as the images are loading. You could preload paths using `new Image().src = [path]`, or use image sprites and css clip to make it more seamless.

Comment: So, image.src = randomImage goes into the <img/> tag itself?

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin.